# How to define @rpath while running an electron application in mac

Tags: macos, electron, rpath

How can I define the `@rpath` of an electron application that I'm running from terminal as below:

```
electron app.js
```

This project depends upon certain libraries of VLC player, which use `@rpath` for defining library locations. This is how the question came up for me.